# Coordinating thread timer with particular minutes in each block

Tags: python, multithreading, time

<sup>I am a total noob to threading, so my apologies if this is trivial - I couldn't find any solution in the [threading docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)</sup>

Suppose that I have a function `f()`

```
def f():
    print('do the useful things!')
```

that I want to execute upon initial call, as well as on the 3rd and 8th minutes of every 10-minute block following the initial call.  **How can I set this up with threading**?

I know that if I wanted the function to be executed every five minutes following the initial call, I could do something like

```
import threading

def f():
    print('do the useful things!')
    threading.Timer(60*5, f).start()
```

But I'm having a difficult time trying to assess how I can easily align the timings with the 3rd and 8th minutes. Really, this would just involve aligning the *next* execution - that is, if I initially called the function at 8:01, then my task is only to ensure that the next execution is at 8:03 after which subsequent executions will be at 8:08, 8:13, etc.. (*which is easy with `threading.Timer`*)

A sort of "hack"-ish seeming solution would be to use a flag to identify the first function call - when the function is first called, get the difference between the current minute and the third or eighth minute that is upcoming... `time.sleep` that difference, and *then* use `threading.Timer`. The problem with this is that `time.sleep` will block the execution of my entire process - this needs to be on another thread. It feels like it would be easier to use `threading.Timer` here as opposed to building my own thread class, but I am not sure.

Comment: look at this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chronos

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I will, thank you.

Comment: you could just pass a sleep time parameter into your threaded function, then run time.sleep for that amount of time

Answer (score -1):

Use a timer event to perform your function ( say every 5 seconds ).  First time thru the timer event perform your function no matter what, on every following event test the clock time for your 3rd or 8th minute.  If its the right time, the do the function.  Otherwise exit the timer event and wait till you enter it again.  Make sure you set a flag if your entered in the event just in case the timer event fires before you have finished dealing with the last event.  Clear the entered flag when you exit the timer event code.